# Set up a cache between application and SQL server

Tags: .net, wpf, caching, redis

we currently employ a set-up where on application start-up we synchronize a lot of data to a local SQL database which in turn provides the data to a local in-house developed WPF application.

We would like to implement something like Redis Cache which stores all of the synchronized data every hour in the cache (about 3-5GB of data) for the first person to synchronize that hour but I'm not sure if this is the way to go on a Windows Server. Are there any other caching solutions for Windows server that are any good?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is a cache going to *help* with synchronization? That's *one more* thing that requires synchronization. Besides - why add a cache? This won't improve bad queries or missing indexes, just cost extra money. The data size is *small* for SQL Server. It's not small for Redis, especially if it ends up eating 3GB from the client's memory. Besides, SQL Server has in-memory tables in all editions, even Express

Comment: What is your *actual* problem? Why don't you want to query the database? How many concurrent clients are there? Are you trying to fix a database design problem by adding yet-another cache, or are you trying to solve a *replication* problem by adding a cache?

Comment: If the actual problem is one of replication, use SQL Server's replication mechanisms. Adding a cache won't help, you still have to write what SQL Server gives you for free.

Comment: We would like to reduce the work load on the sql server since there are currently around 1000~ clients that all need to synchronize their local database with the one on the server. It isn't necessarily bad queries or missing indexes it's mostly just a lot of concurrent workload from clients downloading all that information and we would like to push a lot of the workload to the cache instead of the sql server.

Comment: 1K clients is *not* a lot. You may have 1K clients but not *all* of them execute queries *concurrently*. You should be looking for bad queries, lack of indexing, unfortunate ideas like trying to load entire table in memory to *improve* performance (thus causing a table-wide lock and increased blocking). Long running connections and transactions are another culprit

Comment: *Why* do you thing you need to lighten the load? Why move *3GB* of data? Just throwing a cache won't help. Imagine moving 3**T**B of data every hour to keep the replicated databases in sync. This matters a *lot*. Caching only helps with *lookups*. It won't help with CRUD

Comment: You can use in-memory tables to improve CRUD performance dramatically (100x). Not because they are in-memory (SQL Server caches as much as possible always), but because they use different locking and logging mechanisms. You can improve reporting performance by using columnstore tables (again 100x). You can minimize IO by using compression.

Comment: So you want to basically replace your database with redis cache so that all clients who need to synchronize data will fetch it from redis instead of main database?